# Rails Migration: indexes on a renamed table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, database-migration

I created a table and added an index to it.
On a second migration I renamed the table.
Will the index keep on working?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Rails 3

No, you'll need to take care of the indexes yourself since the index is based on the table name. For example:

```
remove_index :old_table_name, :column_name
rename_table :old_table_name, :new_table_name
add_index :new_table_name, :column_name
```

## Rails 4+

From [the Rails 4 upgrade guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html):

> In Rails 4.0 when a column or a table is renamed the related indexes are also renamed. If you have migrations which rename the indexes, they are no longer needed.

Comment: In Rails 4+ rename_table will barf if the name of the new index is too long, so in this case your approach is still useful.

Comment: Although Rails 4+ renames the indexes automatically, it got errors and failed to rename. So, this answer is useful.

Comment: Also in Rails 4+ you can use `rename_index :table_name, "oldname", "newname"` in the `change` method. If you get that error "Index name [...] on table 'fertilisation_planning_plot_details' is too long; the limit is 63 characters" rename the index manually first to something short.

Comment: Migrations aren't smart enough to deal with "name too long" problems.  I still always use the rename indexes just to be sure.