# If I rename a database table in Rails 4, how does that affect a database index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I rename a database table in Rails 4.2 via migration will the associated index get taken care of automatically?

Comment: Probable duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701173/rails-migration-indexes-on-a-renamed-table

Answer (score 1):

If you are on `rails 4+` then it is not needed

> In Rails 4.0 when a column or a table is renamed the related indexes are also renamed. If you have migrations which rename the indexes, they are no longer needed.

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

For `rails` version < 4.0 you need to handle it yourself by using `remove_index` (removing old index) and then `add_index` (add new index).